# How add field from database to DropDowList in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I add fields to DropDownlist from database table.
I have table Languages {Id,Name,Price} and Projects {Id,Name,Hours,Languages,Cost}. I have the view when I input data but I want make dropdownlist with name of languages. When I choose the name I want that in database in Projects table the cost = Languages.Price * Hours. Here is my code:

**CreateProject.cshtml**

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Language, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Language, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Language, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

ProjectContlorer.cs

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,ProjectName,HoursEntity,Description,Language,Technology,Cost")] Project project)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.Projects.Add(project);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(project);
        }
```

**Project.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Projectvaluation.Models
{
    [Table("Projects")]
    public class Project
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public float HoursEntity { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
        public string Technology { get; set; }
        public float Cost { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understood your question.

In your view you could change your EditorFor to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Language, Model.Languages, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

I would also recommend to use ViewModels instead of passing your Model to the View. Something like:

```
public class CreateProjectViewModel {

    public string Language { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Languages { get; set; }

}
```

On your ViewModel you would have the list of SelectListItem that holds all elements you want on your dropdown list.

The SelectListItem has a Text (which is displayed) and a corresponding Value.

Finally, on your controller, when building your ViewModel you can populate your dropdown list with the data from your database.

Comment: I add `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Languages { get; set; }` to project model. Now I have an error System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Languages'.' in View on `@Html.DropDownList("Languages", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: @KamilStępniewski Have you populated the IEnumerable Languages in your controller? I've seen your answer. You can populate the IEnumerable the same way you are populating the ViewData.

Answer (score 0):

I find how to create dropdownlist but know languages and technology doeasn't save in my database.Can someone know why it is?

**ProjectController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            using (ApplicationDbContext pvEntity = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var fromDatabaseEF = new SelectList(pvEntity.Languages.ToList(), "Price", "Name");
                ViewData["Languages"] = fromDatabaseEF;
            }

            using (ApplicationDbContext pvEntity = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var fromDatabaseEF = new SelectList(pvEntity.Technologies.ToList(), "Price", "Name");
                ViewData["Technologies"] = fromDatabaseEF;
            }
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Projects/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,ProjectName,HoursEntity,Description,Language,Technology,Cost")] Project project)
        {
            //ViewBag.Languages = new SelectList(db.Languages, "Name", "Price", project.Languages);



            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.Projects.Add(project);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(project);
        }
```

**Project View**

```
div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Language, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Languages", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Languages"],"Choose Languages",new { @class = "form-control" } )
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Language, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Technology, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Technology, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.DropDownList("Technologies", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Technologies"],"Choose Technology", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Technology, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: On your view you are binding the selected language to the field 'Languages'. But, on your model  the field is 'Language'. I would still recommend to use a ViewModel.